# Using mixed models on SPSS for multiple observation per subject across time

Tags: mixed-model, repeated-measures, spss

It's my first question here and I'm french-speaking so bear with me, I'll try to make this as clear as possible =).

I am unsure how to construct my database and how write my syntax (in SPSS) to test a factorial design (3 repeated measures and three group factors) using a mixed model.

I have around 20 animals, belonging to two groups each (10 young and 10 old). I am analyzing a parameter derived from local-field potentials recordings.

Each animal is recorded using 6 electrodes over 24h and I have a variable number of samples per hour (interval).
Sample below.

[image: Database]

Using SPSS, I want to model an effect of age and sex (interindividual variance) and electrodes and interval (repeated measure). I dont care about the slope inside an interval, but I definitely want to account for the different number of timepoints per interval across animals (epochs).

Here is my current syntax.

```
MIXED H BY electrode Age Sexe interval
/CRITERIA=DFMETHOD(SATTERTHWAITE) CIN(95) MXITER(100) MXSTEP(10) SCORING(1) 
  SINGULAR(0.000000000001) HCONVERGE(0.00000001, RELATIVE) LCONVERGE(0, ABSOLUTE) PCONVERGE(0, 
  ABSOLUTE)
/FIXED=electrode Age Sexe interval electrode*Age electrode*Sexe electrode*interval Age*Sexe 
  Age*interval Sexe*interval electrode*Age*Sexe electrode*Age*interval electrode*Sexe*interval 
  Age*Sexe*interval electrode*Age*Sexe*interval | SSTYPE(3)
/METHOD=REML
/REPEATED=interval*epoque*electrode | SUBJECT(souris) COVTYPE(AR1).
```

I am highly unsure of this syntax to correctly account for intraindividual variance linked to three factors : subjects (souris), electrodes (6) and intervals (18). Plus, to account for the variable number of epochs per interval.

Any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated !